# Zipping asynchronously using Task.Run() is blocking UI. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, zip

Part of my process sometimes zips files, and I'm trying to make that process asynchronous. I'm rather new at this.

I've used "await Task.Run(() => DoSomething())" before and did not encounter any issues. For some reason, when my program reaches that awaited Task.Run(), it hangs indefinitely.

Would anyone let me know what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

```
public static async Task<BackupResultHelper> BackupAndZip(List<MyBackupItem> itemList, FileInfo targetFi) {
        DirectoryInfo zipSourceDi = new DirectoryInfo(targetFi.Directory + "\\Temp");

        if (targetFi.Exists)
            targetFi.Delete();

        if (!Directory.Exists(zipSourceDi.FullName))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(zipSourceDi.FullName);

        foreach (MyBackupItem item in itemList) {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(zipSourceDi.FullName + "\\" + item.Name);
            if (!BackupItem(item, dir.FullName)) return ErrorResultHelper;
        }

        await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipSourceDi.FullName, targetFi.FullName, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false));

        Directory.Delete(zipSourceDi.FullName, true);
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        return new BackupResultHelper(){Success = true, Message = "Backup complete!", BackupDateTime = time};
    }
```

Comment: have you called this function with a async event handler?

Comment: @Thomas No I haven't. In my response to Stephen below I linked a gist with the calling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have code further up your call stack that is calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`, and that is where the problem is.

If you are using a UI or ASP.NET request thread to do the processing, and then block on an asynchronous task, you [run the risk of a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. By default, `await` will capture the current "context" (e.g., a UI context) and resume the `async` method in that context (e.g., on the UI thread). If you block that context (e.g., by calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` on the UI thread), then the `async` method cannot resume execution and is prevented from completing that task.

Comment: In this case that isn't the culprit, though I'm sure it's something similarly obvious to you. This is the method that calls the code I posted. https://gist.github.com/rcornell/9291035 The call is in the Switch statement, the second case. This is started by the UI thread always. Your blog is a great read, thanks.

Comment: And what calls `StartBackup`?

Comment: Argh! I found it. There was a ".result" up the stack. Lesson learned. Thanks very much.